# SSRS Network/Working days, using date parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

im using the below function to get network days between the submission date and the day i run the report;
at the same time i am using a date parameter in my SSRS to get the tickets between these dates , my problem is i need the end date of the network days to be the end date of my date parameter, i am not sure how to link them together somehow , specially that this function is on my SQL and the date parameter is on my SSRS

```
alter function [dbo].[days_diff](
                                 @date1 datetime
                                ,@date2 datetime
                                )
returns int
as
    begin
        declare @i int;
        declare @count int;
        declare @diff int;
        set @diff = datediff(d,@date1,@date2);
        set @i = 0;
        set @count = 0;
        while(@i < @diff)
        begin
            select @count = @count + 1
            where datename(dw,dateadd(d,@i,@date1)) not in('Saturday'
                                                          ,'Sunday'
                                                          );
            set @i = @i + 1;
        end;
        return @count;
    end;
```

Comment: A little fuzzy.  Perhaps you could give an example with actual dates and desired results

Comment: What's a network day?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  It is a working day.  I imagine they are referencing the function of the same name that is available in Excel.

Comment: learn something new every day!

Comment: Are you asking for the report to change any dates that are a Saturday or Sunday to be the preceding Friday?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameter values from your report into your dataset's SQL queries by referencing the parameter as a variable that you don't explicitly declare.

For example, to reference a report parameter called `EndDate` you can have a SQL script as follows:

```
declare @FilterValue nvarchar(50) = 'Group1'

select ProjectName
      ,SubmissionDate
      ,@ReportDate as ReportDate
      ,dbo.days_diff(SubmissionDate, @ReportDate) as NetworkDays
from ProjectSubmissions
where FilterValue = @FilterValue
```

that when used in an SSRS dataset will go and look for a report parameter called `ReportDate` to use in the query, which you can set to anything you require in your report design.

Comment: well, my parameter is called enddate, so where should i mention this parameter in select you mentioned above , and do i have to change the variable you created on the top ? declare @FilterValue nvarchar(50) = 'Group1'

Comment: @MustafaEl-Gamal  Please re-read my answer and if you don't understand what is being presented, do some reading on SQL and SSRS.  Per my answer *"You can pass parameter values from your report into your dataset's SQL queries by referencing the parameter as a variable that you don't explicitly declare."*  `@FilterValue` is explicitly declared so it won't take a value from your Report.  `@ReportDate` on the other hand ***isn't*** explicitly declared...

Comment: im sorry, still trying understand the whole thing , but thank you very much